# Inserting zeros into an array and looping using a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have **several arrays** that are calculated example `a,b and c` **(there are more than three)** are calculated:  **Please note this is just an example the numbers are much larger and are not so basic**
 `a=[1,2,3,4,5]` `b=[10,20,30,40,50]` `c=[100,200,300,400,500]` and I want a `for loop` that inserts zeros into it so I can have the `new_abc` array steps look like.

```
    1st for loop step new_abc=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    2nd for loop step new_abc=[1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,5,0,0] 
    3rd for loop step new_abc=[1,10,0,2,20,0,3,30,0,4,40,0,5,50,0] 
    4th for loop step new_abc=[1,10,100,2,20,200,3,30,300,4,40,400,5,50,500]
```

how can I do this with a `for` loop?

I started with the code below which gives me the zeros

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
new_abc=zeros(1,length(a)*(3));
```

But I'm not sure how to place the values of the array `a` `b` and `c` using a `for loop`into the correct locations of`new_abc`

I know I could place all the arrays into one large array and do a reshape but the calculated arrays I use become to large and I run out of ram, so reading / calculating each array and inserting them into one common array `new_abc`using a `for loop` works best.

I'm running octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab.

Comment: How about initalize a `Nx3`, with `N` as `5` here and at each iteration/loop index into each column and set iteratively? At the end of looping,  transpose and reshape.

Comment: @Divakar I know I could place all the arrays into one large array and do a reshape but the calculated arrays I use become to large and I run out of ram, so reading / calculating each array and inserting them into one common array <code>new_abc</code> "on the fly" using a for loop works best.

Comment: If memory is a concern why are you doubling your usage by consolidating the arrays?

Comment: @excaza it doesn’t double it.  In the example following the steps 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, the array <code>new_abc</code> the zeros are overwritten by the calculated arrays

Comment: You still have `a`, `b`, and `c` along with `new_abc`, which is the exact same data. That is double the data.

Comment: @excaza I can do  clear on the a,b, and c arrays once they are inserted into the new_abc array

Comment: It's still double the data until you clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You can put `a,b,c` into a cell array. (you can also put them in a matrix...)

```
new_abc = zeros(1, 3*numel(a));
in = {a, b, c};
for k = 1:3
    new_abc(k:3:end) = in{k};
end
```